# how to clear navigation history on nativescript-vue manual routing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

i am facing a situation where the [navigation calls](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/) just keep stacking as can be seen in the picture bellow.

[image: devtools showing navigation calls]

This is a problem specially because when i call the logout function it just stack another navigation entry and therefore user could use the back button to see previous screens.

Is there a way to clean the navigation entry history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `clearHistory` to `true`

```
// Upon logout, navigate to Login / whichever component you like with `clearHistory` flag
this.$navigateTo(Login, { clearHistory: true });
```